# Putting a limit on the maximum amount of RAM a .NET process can use?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, process

I have a .NET process that, for reasons I will not go into, consumes a large amount of RAM. What I want to do is implement an upper limit on the amount of RAM this process can use. Is there a way to do this?

The closest I have found is `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MaxWorkingSet` which I don't think does what I want based on the documentation I have read.

The best I have come up with is using `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` to get the amount of RAM being used and restart if it is over a certain amount. But this is not ideal.

Comment: You can check your usage and shut yourself down (or write a watchdog to) but you can't make the OS do it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Not at all true. See my answer.

Comment: @JimMischel Its not exactly a hard limit: "The maximum working set size for the process, in bytes. The virtual memory manager attempts to keep no more than this much memory resident in the process whenever the process is active and available memory is low." That said, I didn't know about that function; thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the minimum and maximum sizes of the process's working set by calling [SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686237(v=vs.85).aspx) or [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx).

There is a pinvoke.net entry for [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setprocessworkingsetsize).

Be sure to read the MSDN documentation for whichever function you decide to call.

Note that this doesn't prevent your application from allocating more virtual memory, but rather puts limits on how much physical RAM the process's virtual memory occupies at any given time.

Comment: That is no different from assigning the Process.Min/MaxWorkingSet properties.  Just have a look-see in the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs#505).

Comment: It is my understanding that these are limits used by the virtual manager that will be enforced when the memory is in short supply. As long as enough memory is available, the current working set size is allowed to grow larger than the value in MaxWorkingSet. Thus, not resolving my problem.